# My Blend file is huge and everything is slow, even after deleting almost everything!

Tags: animation, 3d-view, linked-data, motion-capture

My Blend was 7GB and every click took at least seconds to respond.  I had several linked characters that were rigged and have 4k textures and mocap data for animations.  But that was it; no particles or physics.  The poly count was 420,000.  I don't know how it got so big.  I deleted everything besides one character and got it down to 4GB.  Still slow.  I even started a new file and appended that one character and it is 1.5GB and still slow.  How can one character take up so much space?  I have other blend files that are larger than 1.5GB and it is not so slow.
I don't know if anyone can help me without me charing the blend file, but does anyone really want to download a 1.5Gb file?

Comment: Go to menu *File > Clean Up*

Comment: Maybe it is heavy subdivided which mens a lot of verts (poly count of 420k!) Try to decimate the character mesh once or twice.

Comment: Clean up doesn't help much.  420k was for the whole scene.  The character alone is not much at all, since i did manual retopo.